# Save the xml result to a column in a SQL table

Tags: html, sql

I have copied the code somewhere in the internet and have created an html table using something like

```
''FOR XML RAW (''TR''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS ''TBODY''', 
' FOR XML PATH (''''), ROOT (''TABLE'')'`
```

in SQL. The result is as expected which is an HTML table, below is the snippet.

[image]

Can someone point me on how to get the HTML string and save it into a column in my table. My thought was to get the result and save it as a string then insert it into a column in my table but after sometimes I failed.

The code example can be retrieve from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5025/stored-procedure-to-generate-html-tables-for-sql-server-query-output/

Answer (score 0):

Cheers!! it's simple but I went around the globe. What I did was adding `SET @Myvariable =` in the dynamic query. Previously, I have tried so hard to assign the result into a variable outside the dynamic query which will never work for me.

Originally:

```
SET @DynTSQL = CONCAT (
     'SELECT (SELECT '
     , @columnslist
     ,' '
     , @restOfQuery
     ,' FOR XML RAW (''TR''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS ''TBODY'''
     ,' FOR XML PATH (''''), ROOT (''TABLE'')'
     )
```

What I did:

```
SET @DynTSQL = 'SET @SQLQuery1 =('+CONCAT (
     'SELECT (SELECT '
     , @columnslist
     ,' '
     , @restOfQuery
     ,' FOR XML RAW (''TR''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS ''TBODY'''
     ,' FOR XML PATH (''''), ROOT (''TABLE'')'
     )+')'
```

The result will be assigned into the @SQLQuery1.
Cheers!!!